# Antd Select value label

Tags: javascript, select, antd

I have my state with only id's to load the select

```
//ComponentDidMount method
let countries_data = await axios.get('/api/v1/countries/');
countries_data.data.map((data) => {
  countries.push(<Option key={data.id}>{data.name}</Option>);
});
//My Options are a Option Component

//Render method
<Select 
 showSearch
 placeholder={'Country'}
 size={"large"}
 value={this.state.country_id} //Should show the text from option selected
 onChange={this.onChangeCountry}
 filterOption={(input, option) =>
     option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}>
     {countries}
 </Select>
```

The main problem here is I set the value option with a integer the Select will show the number, like 27, 40 but no the country label from the option like Country A, Country B, etc. My problem here is how to set a value setting the value as integer and show me the Option selected from my country array?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `value` attribute to your `<Option />`

```
countries_data.data.map((data) => {
  countries.push(<Option key={data.id} value={data.id}> {data.name} </Option>);
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

Comment: Still show the data.id not the data.name when I reload

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [`Select.Option` API](https://ant.design/components/select/#Option-props), the property `title` sets the title of `Select` after selecting this option.

Moreover, why would you use a `map` without a return value? Use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for this case.

```js
countries_data.data.forEach((data) => {
  countries.push(<Option key={data.id} value={data.name} title={data.name}>{data.name}</Option>);
});
```